# how I control the input string in a form , contain a substring in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The string contain only url with google.it and wikipedia.it. I would have a validation form .IndexOf() not function with the scope

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="formController">
        <input type="url" ng-model="url" name="url" ng-model="url">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("myApp", []) 
        .controller("formController", function($scope) { 
        $scope.url='http://.google.it || http://wikipedia.it' ;
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to compare it:

```
angular.module("myApp", []) 
        .controller("formController", function($scope) { 
        $scope.yourGoogleLink = 'http://.google.it';
        $scope.yourWikiLink = 'http://wikipedia.it';
        //indexOf returns -1 if the string is not found
        if ($scope.yourWikiLink.indexOf($scope.url) === -1 || $scope.yourGoogleLink.indexOf($scope.url) === -1) { 
              alert("no"); 
            } else {
              alert("yes"); }
        })
```

indexOf method:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

the `=` operator gives a new value to a variable while `==` compares the values of two variables. The `===` is used in JavaScript, when the value can be for example either a string, or a number, or null.

for further information about JavaScript operators have a look here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

you also could work on the HTML side, like:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="url != yourGoogleLink || url != yourWikiLink"></div>
```

which would only set the submit button enabled when the address is correct.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

greetings

Comment: Thanks for your answer  but I want to see if the String Entered in the form contains the substring google.it or wikipedia.it . example in javascript: if(string.indexof("google.it")>=0  || string .indexof("wikipedia.it")>=0) return true ; else return false;

Comment: so please mark my answer (if it helped you) as "solved" (the green hook) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `String.prototype.includes()` for searching substrings:

```
var result = $scope.url.includes('google.it') || $scope.url.includes('wikipedia.it');
```

[More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Includes in undefined . I copy my code:
  angular.module("myApp", []) 
   .controller("formController", function($scope) { 
    var result = $scope.url.includes('google.it') || $scope.url.includes('wikipedia.it');
    $("#result").text(result);    
    });
            
</script> 
      

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Angular</h1>
     


    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="formController">
     <input type="url" ng-model="url" name="url" ng-model="url">
    </form>
   <div id="result"></div>
   
</body>

Comment: It's because you probably use ES5, so in this case you can use `indexOf()` method as @messerbill offers you.

Comment: I think then angular scope is not support the indexof() and String.prototype.includes() .

Comment: It must work `var result = $scope.url.indexOf('google.it') !== -1 || $scope.url.indexOf('google.it') !== -1`. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)